# Adding Entities and updating RIA domain service at runtime

Tags: silverlight, runtime, wcf-ria-services

I have a requirement to deliver an app built in silverlight. Once the app has been built and delivered, any new modules that the user would request should be created as separate apps/xap and the user should be able to import the new module into the application. Its like adding new apps in an iphone.

Now prism/mef do allow this kind of capability for the front end but the problem is with the database end. I can add some logic to create new tables for the new module but how can I update the RIA services and edmx file to handle the entities for the new module.

Is it really possible in RIA? or is there any other technology out there that supports this kind of dynamic db update?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just update the model and then re-generate the ria services... any extra code that you write for either ria services or entity framework you should use partial class extensions so that your code doesnt get erased upon updating either.

Comment: Thanks. That's what I am doing now.